# increasing leverage does not increase MDD(maximal draw down) proportionally?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting

I thought increasing leverage by x times will increase mdd x times.

But it actually increases mdd by y which is smaller than x.

Is it always the case?

If so, because leverage increases compound profits very much, I should always use the leverage, if I can keep the mdd which I can bear.

Am i right to think this way?

Comment: How are you measuring DD: in percentage or dollars or points... or...

Comment: I am measuring in percentage